# Returning value to main method in java

Tags: java, methods

I'm new in java and i'm still trying to understand how to return a value and then retrieve it. on this task, the instructions were to use getMinutes(), to return a value to the main method. and then use that value on calcMeth(), to get the calculation.  The code works, but when I run it, the getMinutes(), gets run twice. i want to know how to pass the value of getMinutes() to calcMeth() without twice running the getMinutes()

```
package ch3Hw;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SammysMotto2 {


    public static void main(String[] args){

            getMinutes();
         sammysMotto2();
        calcMeth();


    }


    public static int getMinutes(){  //method 2
        int mins;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the number of minutes for Rental");
        mins=keyboard.nextInt();
        return mins;
    }


    public static void calcMeth(){  //method 3
        int minS;
        int hourS;  // hours 
        int priceH;  // price for hours used
        int remMin;     // minutes over an hour
        int priceMin;   // price of minutes used over an hour
        int totalPrice;

        minS=SammysMotto2.getMinutes(); // anytime i called the method, the method runs again
        hourS=minS/60;
        remMin=minS % 60;
        priceH=hourS*40;
        priceMin=remMin*1;
        totalPrice=priceH+priceMin;
        System.out.println("Total price of rental is $" + totalPrice);


    }

    public static void sammysMotto2(){    //Method 2

        String a  ="SsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSs";
        String b="Ss                                              Ss";
        String c="Ss        Sammy makes it fun in the sun.        Ss";


        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a);


    }

}
```

Comment: You will want to use something like int minutes = getMinutes();

Comment: You call `getMinutes` in the `main` method AND the `calcMeth`, I think you're suppose to only call it from the `main` method and pass the result to `calcMeth` as a parameter

Comment: how do you pass the result from the main to calcMeth as a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `getMinutes` in the `main` method AND the `calcMeth`, I think you're suppose to only call it from the `main` method and pass the result to `calcMeth` as a parameter

Something like...

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int minutes = getMinutes();
    sammysMotto2();
    calcMeth(minutes);

}
```

And you would need to change your `calcMeth` to allow for a value to be past to it, for example...

```
public static void calcMeth(int minS){  //method 3
    int hourS;  // hours 
    int priceH;  // price for hours used
    int remMin;     // minutes over an hour
    int priceMin;   // price of minutes used over an hour
    int totalPrice;

    hourS=minS/60;
```

See [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel first call for getMinutes() method in your main , each time you call or try to get return value of a method . this method will execute all codes inside it before you got its return value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SammysMotto2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    // getMinutes();
    sammysMotto2();
    calcMeth();


}


public static int getMinutes(){  //method 2
    int mins;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of minutes for Rental");
    mins=keyboard.nextInt();
    return mins;
}


public static void calcMeth(){  //method 3
    int minS;
    int hourS;  // hours 
    int priceH;  // price for hours used
    int remMin;     // minutes over an hour
    int priceMin;   // price of minutes used over an hour
    int totalPrice;

    minS=SammysMotto2.getMinutes(); // anytime i called the method, the method runs again
    hourS=minS/60;
    remMin=minS % 60;
    priceH=hourS*40;
    priceMin=remMin*1;
    totalPrice=priceH+priceMin;
    System.out.println("Total price of rental is $" + totalPrice);


}

public static void sammysMotto2(){    //Method 2

    String a  ="SsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSs";
    String b="Ss                                              Ss";
    String c="Ss        Sammy makes it fun in the sun.        Ss";


    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(a);


}

}
```

Comment: *"on this task, the instructions were to use getMinutes(), to return a value to the main method. and then use that value on calcMeth(), to get the calculation"* maybe it's just me, but that reads that the value returned from `getMinutes` (called in `main`) should be passed to `calcMeth`